# How to sort 1000000 elements array in alphanumeric in mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, sorting, data-structures

**here, I have carrier array in MongoDB, which has 1000000 elements,how to sort carrier array by alphanumerically on the name field**

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"arraySize" : 1000000,
"carrier" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "AB"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "AD"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "CD"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "DC"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "ZY"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$unwind: "$carrier"},
   {$sort: {"carrier.name": 1}},
   {$group: {_id: "$_id", carrier: {$push: "$carrier"}}}
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N6WxSanvytK)